# Will [FromBody] always save me from the parameter never being null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Method(string value, [FromBody] Person person)
```

Can `person` ever be null here?

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that the person object has alteast one property marked with `[Required]` attribute, and that i'm receiving `A non-empty request body is required`

Comment: You could simply try it out, I guess?

Comment: `[FromBody]` says that it should come from the body, not that it is `[Required]`

Comment: Try sending nothing and look and see if `person` is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can still be null.  Example, if your person has an int Age parameter and somehow you pass a string to it that doesn't parse to an integer, it will be null.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course it can be. If no property on person is submitted, it will be null. The modelbinder only instantiates an instance of the action parameter class if it has something to bind to it. If it has nothing to bind (either because nothing was posted or posted values were invalid (submitting an empty string for an int, for example), then the parameter will be null.

Comment: Maybe he thought that the "MVC Routing" will prohibit it and not even forward it to the action, if `person` is null.

Comment: This is not true, I tested and even though I pass an empty JSON (that is `{ }`), it _will_ bind and person will be an object, but it's properties will be null. On the other hand - if _nothing_ is passed in the body, then person is indeed null.